# ReactJS App deployed on Google Cloud Run, takes around 20 seconds to load

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, surveyjs

My reactJS app is simple app which contains embedded SurveyJS widget. Deployed on Google Cloud Run, and it takes 20 seconds to load first time, subsequent access is faster.

How to troubleshoot, not sure it is Google Cloud Run config issue, or my docker file issue.
Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks,

Comment: Did it take 20 seconds when running locally? Please share minimal reproducible code snippet and Cloud Run configuration in order to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that these 20 seconds can due to the Cloud Run Cold-start.

The first time that a Cloud Run instance starts running requires downloading the container image and starting the container. This time is called “cold start”. The opposite is “warm start” which means that the container is already running waiting for or already processing requests.

Please have a look into the following [Cloud Run Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/3-ways-optimize-cloud-run-response-times) in order to minimize the cold-start. Also please have a look into the following [external tutorials](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-minimizing-cold-starts/) ,  [3](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894) which explains regarding the cold-start and possible ways to minimze it.

Comment: After setting 'minimum instance' to 2. the issue is resolved. Thank you so much.

Comment: Related question is being discussed here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48539